# PayPal Express Check Out Recurring Payments ignoring some SetExpressCheckout parameters

Tags: paypal, payment, recurring

Except as detailed below, my flow is working in both sandbox and live.

I set urlencoded nvp `SURVEYENABLE=1&SURVEYQUESTION=test&L_SURVEYCHOICE0=yes&L_SURVEYCHOICE1=no`, but buyer is never shown survey; `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` does not contain `SURVEYQUESTION` or `SURVEYCHOICESELECTED`.

I set urlencoded nvp `ALLOWNOTE=1`, but buyer is never shown the note text input box; `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` does not contain `NOTE`. However, if I set `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTETEXT="seller test note"`, this is passed to  `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` (just as if it was `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM`).

Problem is seen both live and in sandbox.

Comment: What "VERSION" are you using? If it is one before the survey feature was introduced you won't see it. Are you able to provide a copy of the request and response?

Comment: This is METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
VERSION=98
USER=...
PWD=...
SIGNATURE=...
RETURNURL=http%3A%2F%2F...
CANCELURL=http%3A%2F%2F...
LANDINGPAGE=Login
REQCONFIRMSHIPPING=1
NOSHIPPING=0
ALLOWNOTE=1
SOLUTIONTYPE=Mark
L_BILLINGTYPE0=RecurringPayments
L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0=TODO
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=TODO
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=TODO
L_NUMNER0=TODO
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM=TODO
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTETEXT=TestNote
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=0.00
SURVEYENABLE=1
SURVEYQUESTION=Hello
L_SURVEYCHOICE0=No
L_SURVEYCHOICE1=Yes

Comment: @plmp2013 can u know me how can i set this type functionality in my paypal payment.in my app there some service that payment is done every month and implement the PayPal Express Check Out but i don't know how i achieve recurring payment.

Answer (score 0):

The survey options are apparently not supposed to work with Recurring Payment transactions. When I remove those options from the request and test it with my own credentials the note and survey appeared correctly.

I'll submit a feature request to allow surveys with a Recurring Payment creation but I can't be sure it will be implemented.

In your request you have `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=TODO L_NUMBER0=TODO` set. You don't need the `L_NUMBER0=TODO` set